# Getting every even child of class within variable container

Tags: css, css-selectors

Currently styling a react application where I need to create styling for the following elements but can't seem to figure out a selector which does it properly.

```css
    .FORM__field--50:nth-of-type(even) {
     background-color: red;
    }
```

```html
<div class='SECTION'>
 <div class='SECTION__title'>Some title</div>
 <div class="FORM__field FORM__field--50">Content</div>
 <div class="FORM__field FORM__field--50">Select this</div>
 <div class="FORM__field FORM__field--50">Content</div>
 <div class="FORM__field FORM__field--50">Select this</div>
 <!-- can go on forever -->
</div>

<div class='SECTION'>
 <div class="FORM__field FORM__field--50">Content</div>
 <div class="FORM__field FORM__field--50">Select this</div>
 <!-- can go on forever -->
</div>

<div class="SECTION">
    <div class='SECTION__title'>some subtitle</div>
 <div class="FORM__field">
  <div class="FORM__field--50">Content</div>
  <div class="FORM__field--50">Select this</div>
  <div class="FORM__field--50">Content</div>
  <div class="FORM__field--50">Select this</div>
  <div class="FORM__field--50">Content</div>
  <div class="FORM__field--50">Select this</div>
  <!-- can go on forever -->
 </div>
</div>
```

Tried the following css however in the first case for some reason it selects the wrong (odd) of the `FORM__field--50` class.

Comment: @NenadVracar sorry, removed that (was coming from JSX)

Comment: @NenadVracar Was my fault as I created `h1` and `h2` tags which are `div` in the real case, see adjusted question.

Comment: What about this https://jsfiddle.net/f3mwuqLt/?

Comment: @j08691 again breaks down if there are more `FORM__field--50` then the 2 in the example.

Comment: Can you post a more representative HTML example?

Comment: @j08691 see new html

Comment: I think you will need js for this, https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1900/.

Comment: @NenadVracar you were so close with your fiddle before the jquery, the only issue is that the title is not always present. See updated question (html)

Answer (score 1):

`x:nth-of-type(n)`  Selects every `<x>` element that is the nth `<x>` element of its parent. So with the title present, the first `FORM__field FORM__field--50` becomes the 2nd thus the even child. You can just wrap the `FORM__field FORM__field--50` inside another `div` to fix that, if you just want a css fix.

```css
.FORM__field--50:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='SECTION'>
  <div class='SECTION__title'>Some title</div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="FORM__field FORM__field--50">Content</div>
    <div class="FORM__field FORM__field--50">Select this</div>
    <div class="FORM__field FORM__field--50">Content</div>
    <div class="FORM__field FORM__field--50">Select this</div>
  </div>
  <!-- can go on forever -->
</div>

<div class='SECTION'>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="FORM__field FORM__field--50">Content</div>
    <div class="FORM__field FORM__field--50">Select this</div>
  </div>
  <!-- can go on forever -->
</div>

<div class="SECTION">
  <div class='SECTION__title'>some subtitle</div>
  <div class="FORM__field">
    <div class="FORM__field--50">Content</div>
    <div class="FORM__field--50">Select this</div>
    <div class="FORM__field--50">Content</div>
    <div class="FORM__field--50">Select this</div>
    <div class="FORM__field--50">Content</div>
    <div class="FORM__field--50">Select this</div>
    <!-- can go on forever -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: Since your third group has a `FORM__field` div, you could use the same for all of the above, if it doesn't introduce additional styles.

```css
.FORM__field--50:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='SECTION'>
  <div class='SECTION__title'>Some title</div>
  <div class="FORM__field">
    <div class="FORM__field FORM__field--50">Content</div>
    <div class="FORM__field FORM__field--50">Select this</div>
    <div class="FORM__field FORM__field--50">Content</div>
    <div class="FORM__field FORM__field--50">Select this</div>
  </div>
  <!-- can go on forever -->
</div>

<div class='SECTION'>
  <div class="FORM__field">
    <div class="FORM__field FORM__field--50">Content</div>
    <div class="FORM__field FORM__field--50">Select this</div>
  </div>
  <!-- can go on forever -->
</div>

<div class="SECTION">
  <div class='SECTION__title'>some subtitle</div>
  <div class="FORM__field">
    <div class="FORM__field--50">Content</div>
    <div class="FORM__field--50">Select this</div>
    <div class="FORM__field--50">Content</div>
    <div class="FORM__field--50">Select this</div>
    <div class="FORM__field--50">Content</div>
    <div class="FORM__field--50">Select this</div>
    <!-- can go on forever -->
  </div>
</div>
```